# conditionally average excel data columns

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, average

I have a health project spreadsheet that has a column of a symptoms and drugs a patient is taking. 
These are actually columns but I don't know how to write a column in stack overflow.

```
symptom   drug1    drug2
7         150       0
6         150       0
7         150       0
6         150       0
2         75        25
3         75        25
2         75        25
3         75        25
```

I need help writing a formula that will average all the days with a symptom level 6 and above vs all the days with a symptom level of 3 and below.  Then apply it to the drug column days. For instance in the case above it looks like the symptom level is higher when taking more of drug1 and less of drug 2. Right now I am doing this by hand by marking the days manually.

Since the symptom may be determined by the last x days of the drug value I'd like the drug value to be the average of X days back also.   I'm also doing this manually by going a few days back each time I mark the days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then this is absolutely possible. Below is a screenshot of what I was able to create:

[image: Excel Worksheet1]

This gives you the averages for the amount of each drug, only when it is `>=` or `<=` the specified symptom level.

The formula is as follows, but instead of hitting `ENTER` after typing, you must hit `CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER`:

```
=AVERAGE(IF($B$1:$I$1<=3,B2:I2))
```

Here is what it looks like in Excel:

[image: Excel Worksheet2]

As you can see, the formula only averages the data that meet the requirement. For other uses of this conditional functions, the logic test can be replaced (numbers, strings, dates, etc) and the function can also(`sum`, `average`, `min`, `max`, `count`, etc.)

If you try this and end up with `#VALUE` then you skipped the important step!

**After typing the formula, HIT `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`**

By hitting that key combo Excel knows that the data in your form should be an array of either cells or ranges, instead of individual cells or individual ranges.

[Check out this link for more info about Excel Array Formulas](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/arrays.htm)

Comment: It's interesting that you can do this by dragging. My data is in columns though.  Is there a way to average the symptom or drug 3 days back in the conditional? Like the symptom average of the last 3 days has to be less than 3

Comment: Well it doesn't matter whether it's columns or rows, it's just how you select your data. As for your second question, it's kinda hard to understand, "average the symptom or drug 3 days back" is somewhat confusing, so please explain more. If you are now concerned about days, also add another row/column to show the day numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The formula you are looking for is `AVERAGEIF` I think.

Something like this:

```
=AVERAGEIF(R2C1:R9C1,">=6",R2C2:R9C2)
=AVERAGEIF($A$2:$A$9,">=6",$B$2:$B$9)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I looked up averageif. I understand averageif. Am I supposed to use these equations together? I'm trying to plug them into excel to see what they do changing the column labels R to A and C to B  but I am gettting div/o.  Also I've never seen anything like R2C1 before. My background is in javascript programming.

Comment: =AVERAGEIF($A$1:$A$10,">=1",B1:B10) this seems to work for checking any one column against the first column.

Comment: @danielsavage - To use "R1C1" addresses you need to put excel into "R1C1" mode, otherwise it uses the default "A1" mode. Using "R1C1" is often easier than "A1", but it takes time to get used to.