# conditional average in excel

Tags: excel, average

I have an excel sheet where these are the columns:

`% of contract value = c(4,3,5,6)`

`contract type = c("sell", "sell", "sell", "buy")`

`confidence = c(5, 3, 3, 3)`.

I would like to do a conditional average as follows:

take the average of `% of contract value` but only for rows where `contract type = "sell"` and `confidence = 3`.

In other words the answer to this should be `(3 + 5)/2 = 4`

Is there an easy way to do this in excel????

Comment: Possible duplicate of [conditionally average excel data columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592926/conditionally-average-excel-data-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the purpose of the c(bla,bla,bla) notation if this is in an Excel worksheet? If your data is arranged in a table, then you can easily use the AverageIfs function.

=AVERAGEIFS(B2:B5,C2:C5,"sell",D2:D5,3)

[image]

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what I was after!  Stack overflow wouldn't let me paste an image into the question so I just wrote in the clearest way I though people would get.